# Help with nested foreach loops

Tags: php

I am trying to ultimately find files in a directory that are no longer being used and delete them. I am using a field in my database to match against the filenames; they are the same.

The outer loop is for the database values and the inner loop is for the files in the directory. I'm using an if stmt inside the inner loop but I am getting files showing up in the output that should not be there. What am I doing wrong?

If I have a file in my directory and no matching database value, I want to delete the file.

```
                foreach( $ds as $id ){
                    foreach( $out as $file ){
                        if( $file != $id['patient_id'] ){
                            echo $id['patient_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furthering @DarkDust's answer, a fairly efficient way of doing it (assuming you're using raw PHP as opposed to a framework) would be something along the lines of:

```
$files = array()
$rows = array();

while($add = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT filename FROM files')) {
  $rows[] = $add[0]
}

...files code

foreach(array_diff($files, $rows) as $deletable) {
  unlink('/path/to/'.$deletable);
}
```

Comment: Steve, thanks again. Your first suggestion worked as well as DarkDusts. My issue was that when I did a print_r, I found that my database array as multidimensional and I don't believe that in_array as well as array_diff work on multidimensional arrays. I rebuilt the MD array and life is once again, well, good. Thanks for the help

Comment: I figured that might be an issue, hence the `$add[0]` :)

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say using nested foreach loops for this in the first place is a bad idea; and also it looks to me logically that you have these the wrong way round- shouldn't file be on the outside?

I'd suggest building an array from your database then looping over the files as you are there and do an `in_array` to determine whether or not to delete them- the way you're doing it would loop over all the files for every row of results; that can't be good.

Comment: Exactly, Steve. I was saying the same thing. I only have about 1000 rows in the db now and for each row of data, I'd get 1000 iterations. Absolutely correct. Thanks for the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do any PHP any more so I can't give you a concrete answer, but I can tell how such a problem can be solved on a higher level: what you want is to know whether some entries in a set (files on disk) are not in another set (database). You can solve this with a set difference: set(files on disk) - set(database) = set(files to delete). So you first need an array that has all the entries of your db's patient_id fields. You already seem to have an array with the filenames. It seems that to calculate the set difference on PHP, you can use the array_diff method as in:

```
$files_to_delete = array_diff($out, $patient_ids)
```

Sorry for the vague answer, hope it's of use nevertheless.

Comment: Darkdust, thanks for the answer as well as the great explanation. I've tried Steve's suggestion as well as yours but I am still getting a result that is wrong.

Comment: If you're still around, maybe you can lend a hand.

Comment: `var_dump` your 2 arrays and ensure their formatting is the same i.e. just the filename (assuming all files are in the same directory). Confirming that, if you're still getting a result that is wrong then either your database or files aren't what you're expecting them to be.